# How to calculate the center of the circumcircle of the triangle formed by three geographic coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates, localization

Where is the center of those 3 geographic coordinates as an example:

```
    double latA = 37.418436;
    double lonA = -121.963477;

    double latB = 37.417243;
    double lonB = -121.961889;

    double latC = 37.418692;
    double lonC = -121.960194;
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos please don't use tracking link shorteners in a comment like this; https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 is short enough to include in a 500 character comment. Using link shorteners where not necessary does not live up to many user's quality standards in [predictability of where links go](https://goo.by/cvpOXx) (I hope this illustrates the problem well).

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is the first good piece of advice that I got in a long time concerning my standard comments.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks! I was afraid I was being to cheeky there :)